# Use JS to change bracketed text with link to specified page

Tags: javascript

I would like a way to replace the bracket text everywhere on a page with a link.  I know this could be done serverside with php/etc, but I would be able to include this script to be able to simply be included and to handle the replacement itself.

For example:

If [page=12] is found within the page I would like to link it to:
to change it to:
http://www.example.com/pages/12  ( a clickable link ).

Thanks!

Comment: This is not that easy you might think. Using `innerHTML` is probably slow and using DOM operations is tricky since you need to replace a text node by three new nodes (text, A element, text).

Comment: Are you using any js frameworks?
Isn't this more of a php thing to do?

Comment: I am using jQuery.  Yes I know the obvious solution is to use php, but unfortunately because it has to be installed a few different sites, some that I don't control directly, I would like to make it as simple as possible.  Simply requiring them to include a single JS file.

Comment: @Rob:  you don't have server-side scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as I described in the comments:

```
var stack = [Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].childNodes)], nodes, node, parent, text, offset;
while (stack.length) {
    nodes = stack.pop();
    for (var i=0, n=nodes.length; i<n; ++i) {
        node = nodes[i];
        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                if (node.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "SCRIPT") {
                    stack.push(Array.prototype.slice.call(node.childNodes));
                }
                break;
            case Node.TEXT_NODE:
                text = node.nodeValue;
                offset = text.indexOf("[page=");
                if (offset >= 0 && text.substr(offset).match(/^(\[page=(\d+)\])/)) {
                    parent = node.parentNode;
                    var before = document.createTextNode(text.substr(0, offset));
                        link = document.createElement("a"),
                        after = document.createTextNode(text.substr(offset + RegExp.$1.length));
                    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.substr(offset, RegExp.$1.length)));
                    link.setAttribute("href", "http://www.example.com/pages/" + RegExp.$2);
                    parent.insertBefore(after, node);
                    parent.insertBefore(link, after);
                    parent.insertBefore(before, link);
                    parent.removeChild(node);
                    stack.push([after]);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
text.replace(/\[page=(\w+)\]/g, '<a href="http://example/pages/$1">http://example/pages/$1</a>')
```

As for finding *everywhere on the page*, you don't really want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex to do it:

```
var str = "This is a link: [page=12]"

str = str.replace(/\[page=([^\]]*)\]/g,
    '<a href="www.example.com/pages/$1">www.example.com/pages/$1</a>');
```

This will match [page=testing] as well.